# Error using DMS with parallel-load to a Redshift Destination

Tags: parallel-processing, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

We are using **AWS DMS**

The replication Source is a Aurara MySQL cluster containing a large table.

The replication Target is a Redshift cluster.

Full-load and CDC tasks run successfully without parallel-load.

When using the parallel-load parameter, the task failed with this error :

```
[TARGET_LOAD ]E: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 40P01 
NativeError: 30 Message: [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 40P01] 
ERROR: deadlock detected, 
DETAIL: Process XXXX waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation XXXXXX of database XXXXXX; 
blocked by process 2228., Process 2228 waits for ShareRowExclusiveLock on relation XXXXXX of database XXXXXX; 
blocked by process XXXX. [1022502] (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4638)
```

I suppose the problem comes from DMS sending queries to Redshift that lock the table.

I failed to find information on line (stackoverflow, AWS forums, AWS Doc)

What can I do to solve the problem ?
Is there a known bug with Redshift and DMS parallel-load ?

Parallel-load is quite recent and described here :
https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/database/introducing-aws-dms-replication-engine-version-3-1-2/
 and in the AWS DOC

Comment: Have you tried contacting AWS support?

Comment: Sadly I can't with the current support plan of my client.

Comment: I can confirm this; am hitting it with a large MongoDB collection we're attempting to import into Redshift.

Comment: The docs don't list Redshift as a supported target for the parallel feature :/  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Tablesettings.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Tablesettings.ParallelLoad

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "`TargetTablePrepMode`", set to drop the table and recreate,
`AccessExclusiveLock` is needed for `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP`, or `TRUNCATE`.